# JSF doesn't output the non-strict html

Tags: jsf, escaping

I need to output the html text, which is stored in database. The text is generated by the rich editor, so contains bad-formed html (non-closed tags like `<br>`). So I have the problem how to print it on the page.

If I use:

```
#{document.content}
```

It prints the escaped html document, and all tags are displayed on the page (the code itself contains "& lt;" instead of <)

The visible solution - to use h:outputText with escape="false:

```
<h:outputText value="#{document.content}" escape="false" />
```

But it prints the html only until it is well-xml-formed: the text is stopped on the first `<br>` tag. Seems, JSF parses the content of the document.content and stops when cannot do it. I don't really need JSF to parse the content, simply output!

The following code didn't help either:

```
<h:outputText value="lt![CDATA[#{document.content}]]gt" escape="false" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that seemed to be Chrome error. After I changed *DOCTYPE* to **html transitive** it showed "**Entity ‘nbsp’ not defined**" error and didn't render the content. But in other browsers everything rendered ok! Even after I rollbacked the *DOCTYPE* to **xhtml strict** - Firefox and Opera displayed the content perfectly and didn't pay much attention to bad-formed html!

Didn't dive deep, but this is somehow linked with **Webkit** - the engine for Chrome.

**Update**: use < f:view contentType="text/html" > so that this worked ok in Chrome and Safari.

Hope this will help anyone else